# Modifying rewrite rules to use <custom post type>/category/<custom taxonomy term>/

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I know I can add a rewrite rule to accomplish this but I'd like to affect the links generated by WordPress (such as when I put a custom taxonomy term into a menu)

I have spent the entire day today trying to work this out so at the moment I am assuming that this isn't possible.

Can anyone prove me wrong?

Here is the code I am using to register my post type and taxonomy:

```
$labels = array(
    'name'              => 'Event categories',
    'singular_name'     => 'Event category',
    'search_items'      => 'Search Event categories',
    'all_items'         => 'All Event categories',
    'parent_item'       => 'Parent category',
    'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Event category:',
    'edit_item'         => 'Edit Event category',
    'update_item'       => 'Update Event category',
    'add_new_item'      => 'Add New Event category',
    'new_item_name'     => 'New Event category Name',
    'menu_name'         => 'Event categories'
);
$args = array(
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'slug'              => array( 'slug' => 'events-category' )
                        // 'events/category' doesn't work
);
register_taxonomy( 'events-category', null, $args );

$labels = array(
    'name'                => 'Events',
    'singular_name'       => 'Event',
    'menu_name'           => 'Events',
    'parent_item_colon'   => 'Parent Event:',
    'all_items'           => 'All Events',
    'view_item'           => 'View Event',
    'add_new_item'        => 'Add New Event',
    'add_new'             => 'Add New',
    'edit_item'           => 'Edit Event',
    'update_item'         => 'Update Event',
    'search_items'        => 'Search Event',
    'not_found'           => 'Not found',
    'not_found_in_trash'  => 'Not found in Trash',
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => 'event',
    'description'         => 'An Event',
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'events-category' ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'event', $args );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register your taxonomy, set the `slug` parameter of `rewrite` to your desired structure:

```
register_taxonomy(
    'custom_tax',
    'custom_post_type',
    array(
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'your-cpt-slug/category' ),
        // your other args...
    )
);
```

Comment: Sorry this didn't work for me :( I don't think it likes the `/` in the slug, and just uses the default instead (taxonomy name)

Comment: Add the full code you use to register your taxonomy and post type to your question.

Comment: Also, just to verify, you are currently using pretty permalinks and they work for other post types, yes?

Comment: I have added in the code now. And yes, of course I have pretty permalinks activated :P

Comment: Your slug parameter is being ignored because its in the wrong place. Note that it should be in an array under `rewrite`.

Comment: So it is.. :facepalm: In which case your solution does work thank you very much :)